# What's best way to inject context in my base repository?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository, unit-of-work

I have a *BaseRepository* that depends a `DbContext` to perform the database operations:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
   ...
}
```

I don't want to insert this dependency using *Constructor Dependency Injection*, because if I use I'll need to pass these dependency in constructors of derived repositories. I don't want to use *Property/Setter Dependency Injection* too because *Property/Setter Dependency Injection* indicates dependency is optional, which is not the case.

My `DbContext` inherit from `IDbContext` interface, where is my *UnitOfWork Pattern*:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IDbContext
{
   ...
}
```

And I've set my `IDbContext` using *Ninject*:

```
public override void Load()
{
   Bind<IDbContext>().To<DbContext>().InRequestScope();
}
```

My question is how I inject `DbContext` in Base Repository, and I need a single instance of `DbContext` in a requestScope. (Using a Factory?)

Comment: Even you do not like constructor injection I would recommend this one because most clean and transparent way

Comment: What's wrong with passing dependencies into constructors of derived repositories?

Comment: @DanM hmmm, if all derived class will pass the same dependency, why not to get this dependency only in base class?

Comment: Even with a Factory/Builder you have to expose that dependency via the base .ctor or a Property. Or I guess you could retrieve the dependency in the base .ctor with a call to the container (messy).

Comment: @Acaz Souza : to `get this dependency only in base class` you can do it only using IoC container or static classes. Exposing it via ctor to derived classes cleanly describes them for its clients (clients of derived classes will see this as ctor argument as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the Service Locator of Ninject and took back the instance of `DbContext`:

```
public class ExampleClass()
{
    protected DbContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
                                                                        //Here I do the trick I wanted
            return DependencyResolverFactory.Instance.Get<IDbContext>() as DbContext;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And my Dependency Resolver class:

```
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;

    static DependencyResolver()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        _kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public static IKernel GetCurrentKernel()
    {
        return _kernel;
    }

    public static void RegisterKernel(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public static T Get<T>()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally since your repository *needs* a `DBContext` you should use constructor injection - the context is not optional.

If your repository instances are created using Ninject it does not matter that you need to pass in a `DBContext` - the dependency will be resolved for you.

If you want to "manually" create repository instances you can use a factory that already has the `DBContext` dependency so consumers don't have to worry about it.

Comment: How this factory will get the DBContext dependency? (Remember DbContext is a singleton in a request scope)

Comment: @AcazSouza: Ah yes that is a problem - worst case the factory could Resolve the dependency via Ninject, but this is not clean. How do you instantiate repositories currently?

Comment: I pass repositories via *Constructor Dependency Injection* in my Controllers.

Comment: That makes things easy for you - if the repository is resolved using Ninject it will resolve the constructor dependency automatically for you. In this case I would stick to constructor injection.

Comment: but there are other classes in which I manually instantiate and depends of *IDbContext*. How I'll resolve that classes?